# Show Preview of Images or Video from Links embedded within a Text on LinkedIn

Tags: javascript, node.js, linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

I am working with the LinkedIn Shares API and I use the below code to share content to LinkedIn.
The problem is that if the text contains a video link or image link, LinkedIn doesn't know how to grab the Link from the text and show a Preview of the image or video.

E.g imagine the text says

> Hello world and has an embedded  **[YouTube Link Like this](http://#)** and more text here

How can I make LinkedIn pick up the YouTube link from the text and preview it?

Here is my code:

```
let postUrl = `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares`;
let headers = {
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${access_token}`,
    'X-Restli-Protocol-Version': '2.0.0'
};
let requestBody = {
    text: {
        text: `Hello world and has an embedded  **[YouTube Link Like this][1]** and more text here`
    },
    "distribution": {
        "linkedInDistributionTarget": {}
    },
    owner: `urn:li:organization:${organization.id}`
};
let pagePostResponse = await axios.post(postUrl, requestBody, {
    headers: headers
});
//The content gets posted successfully to LinkedIn but the youtube link preview is not showing
```

Thank you

Comment: Your request doesn't seem to include a link. How would you expect LinkedIn to "*pick up on it*" if you don't include the link in your POST body...?

Comment: @esqew Please how can I include a link in the request body? Thank you

Comment: For starters, why not put it in the `text` property of your `requestBody`?

Comment: @esqew If I put it in the `text` property then where do I put the `caption`? Thanks

Comment: It's not clear to me what `caption` is in this context, you haven't mentioned it in your question or your comments to this point.